# Husky pre-commit hook failing (windows vs. mac)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, husky

I am running vscode on my Windows 10 machine and trying to push commits to github.

All of the devs on my team use Macs, and when they set up the test repository they added a check that none of the names of the tests could use ".only" in the name (due to people re-naming the one they were working on and forgetting to re-name it before committing).

However, a lot of our validation tests use the word "only" in the descriptions (i.e., "drawer can only be 18"). Husky comes back with a failure (Found .only here).

This works on Mac. Any ideas why it's working differently on Windows?

```
husky > pre-commit (node v12.16.3) 
Stashing changes... [started] 
Stashing changes... [skipped] → 
No partially staged files found... 
Running linters... [started] 
Running tasks for src/**/*.{js,jsx,json,css} [started] 
prettier --config ./.prettierrc --write [started] 
prettier --config ./.prettierrc --write [completed] 
git add [started] 
git add [completed] 
Running tasks for src/**/*.{js,jsx,json,css} [completed] 
Running linters... [completed] 
Found .only here 
...
husky > pre-commit hook failed (add --no-verify to bypass)
```

Comment: Show the relevant code where the validation happens.

Comment: husky > pre-commit (node v12.16.3)
Stashing changes... [started]
Stashing changes... [skipped]
→ No partially staged files found...
Running linters... [started]
Running tasks for src/**/*.{js,jsx,json,css} [started]
prettier --config ./.prettierrc --write [started]
prettier --config ./.prettierrc --write [completed]
git add [started]
git add [completed]
Running tasks for src/**/*.{js,jsx,json,css} [completed]
Running linters... [completed]
Found .only here 

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add extra information to the body of the question. Please use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to ensure that it is easily readable.